# My Rdlc works on my computer but not on the server

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, parameters, rdlc

here we got an old DB on progress and we want to print labels from it using vs2012, we found that the mean to do this is by a WCF and a rdlc,
At localhost it runs great, I can get the labels printed and the log files show that all the information is ok, but when I run it on the server (by the progress DB or by the WcfTestClient.exe) it's giving me an error, my log file shows that the report is not ready for render, even when I run it using the same parameters,

I don't use any dataset because the report just need the parameters to print the labels.

Please don't be rude, I'm really new at this, 2 weeks ago I didn't know what was Wcf, rdlc, SSRS and nothing about that, this is all new for me so expect some noobish mistakes.

Here is the piece of code that runs well on localhost but not on server;

```
Public Class GoPrint
Shared Sub StartPrinting(ByVal vpdfname As String, ByVal vExt As String, ByVal vPDFPath As String, ByVal deviceInfo As String, ByVal StreamPath As String, ByVal vReportPath As String, ByVal vReportEmbedded As String, ByVal vPrinter As String, ByVal vParams As String) 'Viene de R4, inicia el proceso y manda parametros
    On Error GoTo Issues
    Registro("StartPrinting", "--------------------------------------------------------------")
    Dim ErrorEnReferencias As Boolean = False
    If IsNothing(vParams) Then
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Error: Los parametros estaban vacios")
        ErrorEnReferencias = True
    End If
    If Not File.Exists(vReportPath.Replace("|", "\")) Then
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Error: No se encontro el path del reporte")
        ErrorEnReferencias = True
    End If
    If Not File.Exists(vReportEmbedded.Replace("|", "\")) Then
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Error: No se encontro el path del reporte incrustado")
        ErrorEnReferencias = True
    End If
    If Not ErrorEnReferencias Then
        Registro("StartPrinting", "No se encontraron errores en los parametros enviados")
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Lista de parametros del reporte excepto vParams (Nombre,Valor):")
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vpdfname = " & vpdfname)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vExt = " & vExt)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vPDFPath = " & vPDFPath)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +deviceInfo = " & deviceInfo)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +StreamPath = " & StreamPath)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vReportPath = " & vReportPath)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vReportEmbedded = " & vReportEmbedded)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "    +vPrinter = " & vPrinter)
        Dim qtyOfParams As Integer = (CountCharacters(vParams, "|"c) / 3)
        Dim SplitParams() As String = vParams.Split(New Char() {"|"c})
        Dim EtqParams() As ReportParameter = New ReportParameter(qtyOfParams - 1) {}
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Lista de parametros (vParam) del reporte (Nombre,Valor,Visible):")
        For count = 1 To qtyOfParams
            If SplitParams(1 + (count * 3 - 3)).IndexOf("[#") <> -1 Then SplitParams(1 + (count * 3 - 3)) = EncodeBarcodes(SplitParams(1 + (count * 3 - 3)))
            EtqParams(count - 1) = (New ReportParameter(CStr(SplitParams(0 + (count * 3 - 3))), CStr(SplitParams(1 + (count * 3 - 3))), SplitParams(2 + (count * 3 - 3))))
            Registro("StartPrinting", "    +" & CStr(SplitParams(0 + (count * 3 - 3))) & "," & CStr(SplitParams(1 + (count * 3 - 3))) & "," & SplitParams(2 + (count * 3 - 3)))
        Next
        Dim permissions As New PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)
        Dim MYreport As LocalReport = New LocalReport()
        MYreport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions)
        MYreport.ReportPath = vReportPath.Replace("|", "\") 'No puedo pasar \ como parametro y mando | para los paths
        MYreport.ReportEmbeddedResource = vReportEmbedded.Replace("|", "\")
        MYreport.DataSources.Clear()
        If MYreport.IsReadyForRendering Then
            Registro("StartPrinting", "MYreport.IsReadyForRendering = Si")
            MYreport.SetParameters(EtqParams)
            MYreport.Refresh()
            Registro("StartPrinting", "Creacion del reporte local y asignacion de propiedades terminada")
            Registro("StartPrinting", "    +MYreport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(permissions), unrestricted")
            Registro("StartPrinting", "    +MYreport.ReportPath = " & MYreport.ReportPath)
            Registro("StartPrinting", "    +MYreport.ReportPath = " & MYreport.ReportEmbeddedResource)
            Registro("StartPrinting", "    +MYreport.SetParameters(EtqParams), (Lista de parametros)")
            Dim PrintReport = New Reporting
            PrintReport.Export(MYreport, vpdfname, vExt, vPDFPath.Replace("|", "\"), deviceInfo, StreamPath.Replace("|", "\"))
            Registro("StartPrinting", "Creacion de pdf y raw de impresion completa")
            PrintReport.Print(vPrinter)
        Else
            Registro("StartPrinting", "MYreport.IsReadyForRendering = No")
        End If
        Registro("StartPrinting", "Proceso finalizado")
        Registro("StartPrinting", "--------------------------------------------------------------")
    End If
Issues:
        Registro("StartPrinting", Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
        Registro("StartPrinting", "--------------------------------------------------------------")
End Sub
```

And here is what shows my log file,

```
Registro de Errores
StartPrinting; -------------------------------------------------------------- -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting; No se encontraron errores en los parametros enviados -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +Lista de parametros del reporte excepto vParams (Nombre,Valor): -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vpdfname = TST00003_1_AmaLbl -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vExt = pdf -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vPDFPath = ||vsn2k841|WCFparaRPT|AmaLbl|PDF| -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +deviceInfo = <DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat><PageWidth>3in</PageWidth><PageHeight>5in</PageHeight><MarginTop>0in</MarginTop><MarginLeft>0in</MarginLeft><MarginRight>0in</MarginRight><MarginBottom>0in</MarginBottom></DeviceInfo> -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +StreamPath = ||vsn2k841|WCFparaRPT|AmaLbl|Stream| -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vReportPath = ||vsn2k841|WCFparaRPT|AmaLbl|AmaLbl.rdlc -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vReportEmbedded = ||vsn2k841|WCFparaRPT|AmaLbl|AmaLbl.rdlc -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +vPrinter = LaserESCLOG -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting; Lista de parametros (vParam) del reporte (Nombre,Valor,Visible): -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSFN,LOUISVILLE LADDER,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSFA,855 DUNKS FERRY RD,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSFZ,19020,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSTN,AMAZON.COM.DEDC LLC,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSTA,1 CENTERPOINT BLVD.,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSTZ,19720,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PBCZ,*19720*,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PCar,UPSA,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PPro,Test ETQ,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PBol,435462,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PPO,TST00003,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PUPC,728865090928,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PQTY,3,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PCartonNo,1,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PCartonTo,1,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PBCPO,*TST00003*,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PBCSSCC,›˜€*hxa$CN4.^œ,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting;     +PSSCC,00107288650435462014,True -- 12/26/2014 5:05:37 PM
StartPrinting; MYreport.IsReadyForRendering = No -- 12/26/2014 5:05:38 PM
StartPrinting; Proceso finalizado -- 12/26/2014 5:05:38 PM
StartPrinting; -------------------------------------------------------------- -- 12/26/2014 5:05:38 PM
StartPrinting; 0  -- 12/26/2014 5:05:38 PM
StartPrinting; -------------------------------------------------------------- -- 12/26/2014 5:05:38 PM
```

The only difference between this log and a working one is that the reports render and keep going on the printing process, I use the exact same parameters,

BTW, already got my dlls on the bin folder.

Comment: Just an Update, I changed the properties reportpath and reportembeddedresource for a stream

    Dim streamrdlc As FileStream =     File.OpenRead(vReportPath.Replace("|", "\"))
    MYreport.LoadReportDefinition(streamrdlc)

Still working localhost but not on server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working some days ago, I was ussing 2 dlls from Microsoft.reportviewer.common and microsoft.reportviewer.webforms, both v10, I was getting them also in my bin folder folder, however, once in the server those dlls weren't working, I had to use the common one v9 and the webform one v11 in order to get this working.